# Record desktop screen with command line tool

Tags: windows, command-line, video, compatibility, screen-recorder

I have to record my desktop screen for at most 30 minutes using command line parameters.

I have an Adobe Air application that works fine with VLC player, it records the screen, but on Linux only — it will not work on Windows.

I need an alternative for that, i.e a command line open-source video screen recorder for Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a Screen Recording program.

[My Screen Recorder Pro 3.1](http://www.deskshare.com/help/msrpro/CommandLineParameters.aspx) supports command line usage (Not Free)

Comment: i need open-source software that can be deployed with my adobe air app..

Comment: Is there any other Screen Recorder Software which supports command line usage ?

Answer (score 1):

CamStudio is free.

http://camstudio.org/

What you're looking for can be called screen recording, screen capturing, or screencasting software.

Answer (score 1):

VLC can record the desktop, though sans audio.